# Creating map from values in app.config

Tags: c#

Currently, in my C# .cs file, I have declared a dictionary as such:

`Dictionary<string, string> example_map = new Dictionary<string, string>();

option_symbol_map.Add("Key11", "Val1");

option_symbol_map.Add("Key2", "Val2");

option_symbol_map.Add("Key3", "Val3");`

I need to move these keys and corresponding values to the app.config file so they can be edited as required.

Whats the best way to implement this?

Should I do it like this:

`<add key="Test1" value="Key1,Key2,Key3"/>

<add key="Test2" value="Val1,Val2,Val3"/>`

And then read both keys simultaneously while creating my dictionary?

or should I list it this way:

`<add key="test3" value="Key1,Val1,Key2,Val2,Key3,Val3"/>`

In this case how would I create my map, selecting every alternate object as key and value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of AppSettings you can write your own `ConfigurationElementCollection` class that reads something like this:

```
<yourSection>
   <yourElements>
       <add key="Key1" value="Val1"/>
       <add key="Key2" value="Val2"/>
       <add key="Key3" value="Val3"/>
    </yourElements>      
</yourSection>
```

Here is an [article](https://web.archive.org/web/20100914104230/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/032807-1.aspx) that covers the most important parts. If you do this then you do not need to know the keys.

Comment: The link to the article is down: https://web.archive.org/web/20100914104230/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/032807-1.aspx works

Answer (score 2):

What is the 'TestX' for? Why not just use

```
<add key="Key1" value="Val1"/>
<add key="Key2" value="Val2"/>
<add key="Key3" value="Val3"/>
```

which fits perfectly with the 'key/value' definition. They can then be accessed like this:

```
string val1 = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Key1"];
```

Comment: TestX is just an arbitrary name I gave to the keys in the app.config.

Comment: I see your solution, but is it wise to have every key,value pair of the dictionary as a key in itself. Wouldn't that bloat the app.config file unnecessarily should the dictionary grow to be quite large?

Comment: You didn't specify how many values you're storing. If you must store them in the app.config, I'd go for readability over parsing huge value1,value2,value3 strings; the data will be there anyway, just more readable... IMO

Comment: Also, in this case, adding the key,value pairs to the dictionary in the program would require me to know beforehand the name of each key in the app.config., wouldn't it?

Comment: That is correct - whatever is in the config file is hard-coded, but you specify the key value anyway, to index into the dictionary.. if the keys are finite, I would create a Constants.cs with 'public const string Key1 = "Key1";'